# Surjectivity of the algebraic K-functor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-k-theory

Let $R \to S$ be a surjective morphism of commutative rings. For a fixed integer $q$, is there any known condition under which the resulting morphism of the K-groups, $K_q(R) \to K_q(S)$ is surjective?

Comment: There's no realtion between one another, except trivial facts like $R\rightarrow S$ being a *split* epi.

Comment: @MatthiasWendt:  I don't think the localization sequence is relevant here; the OP is asking about the map $K_q(R)\rightarrow K_q(S)$, not about a map $K_q(S)\rightarrow K_q(R)$.

Comment: @Muro: Do you mean that if $R \to S$ is a split epimorphism then the corresponding morphism of $K$-groups is surjective?

Comment: @StevenLandsburg: right, I had the direction of the arrow wrong...

Comment: @chotu by functoriality.